# Cannot obtain SQL Server service information - WMI issue?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I right click an SQL server database `MyDB` in SSMS and select "start powershell". However, I got the following error. And it's quite slow?

> WARNING: Could not obtain SQL Server Service information. An attempt to connect to WMI on 'MyServer' failed with the following error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>   cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to 'MyServer\MyDB'. [Failed to connect to server MyServer\MyDB.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>
> At line:1 char:155
>   + ... MyServer\MyDB'']/Database[@Name=''MyDB'']'|cd}
>   + ~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL...s\MyDB:SqlPath)[Set-Location], GenericProviderException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId: ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
>
> cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to 'MyServer\MyDB'. [Failed to connect to server MyServer\MyDB.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>
> At line:1 char:155
>   + ... MyServer\MyDB'']/Database[@Name=''MyDB'']'|cd}
>   + ~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL...RTING\Databases:SqlPath) [Set-Location], GenericProviderException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId: ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
>
> cd : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to 'MyServer\MyDB'. [Failed to connect to server MyServer\MyDB.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>   At line:1 char:155
>   + ... MyServer\MyDB'']/Database[@Name=''MyDB'']'|cd}
>   + ~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL...1\MyDB:SqlPath) [Set-Location], GenericProviderException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Comment: Hi, is the server name `MyServer` and the DB name `MyDB`?

Comment: Yes, they are not entered manually.

Comment: Did you configure your server to allow remote connections ? If not, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18060818/5212566

Comment: @prageeth the ssms can connect the server remotely.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but is it running as admin?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on SSMS icon and select 'Run as Administrator'.
Running SSMS as Administraotr also run Powershell with administrator privileges.